# Mongoid 5.0 - Rails 4 - Collection Form has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I can't get my form working width collection when using has_many in mongoid

Model Line:

```
class Line
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :observations
  field :position, :type => Integer
  field :status, :type => Integer

  has_many :unities, :inverse_of => :unity
end
```

Model Unity:

```
class Unity
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps      
  field :prefix, type: Integer
  field :owner_name
  field :owner_email
  field :owner_phone
  field :document      
  field :license
  field :color
  field :active, type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false
  field :qrx, type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false
  belongs_to :line, index: true
end
```

My form is:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @line do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-2">      
        <%= f.collection_select :unity_id, Unity.all, :id, :title %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm getting this error: undefined method `unity_id' for #

Comment: where is `unity_id `? can you show the code?

Comment: I didn't created. I thougth it wasn't necessary. Do I have to?

Comment: Now it works!!!! When i declared the unity_id it made the trick...

Comment: Do I always have to declare the foreign_key? I saw some examples and didn't see that.

Comment: unity is a model? it belongs to Area or Line?

Comment: Oh....just now I saw I posted the wrong code. sorry. I updated. Yes unity is a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are something wrong with your form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @line do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-2">      
        <%= f.collection_select :unity_id, Unity.all, :id, :title %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

@line has many unities, it doesn't have unity_id field. You are also not defined the `title` field in Line model.

maybe you can do like this:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @unity do |f| %>
    <div class="col-md-2">      
        <%= f.collection_select :line_id, Line.all, :id, :owner_name %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks man! You were right. I was confusing the relations. What a newbie I was. lol